# Change TCombobox Index AND its Text in Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am **trying to change the Index/ItemIndex of a combobox to make the combobox change its text** to the index which belongs to the title of a marker on a map..
Initially this combobox is used to assign some text to a marker which works fine, but when I try to use this combobox to "edit" the title of the marker by assigning the combobox the correct index of a given text which definetely is an item of the combobox the combobox doesnt change its text shown.. for debugging purposes I added the showmessage dialogs and they show me the correct one perfectly fine, but the text of the combobox still doesnt change... what am I doing wrong?

```
ComboBox1.Index := -1;
for I := 0 to ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
begin
    if ComboBox1.Items[I].Equals(Marker.Descriptor.Title)
    then
    begin
        showmessage(ComboBox1.Items[I]+' is working!!!');
        ComboBox1.ItemIndex := I;
        ComboBox1.Index := I;
    end else begin
      showmessage(ComboBox1.Items[I]+' is not working');
    end;
end;
```

using `ComboBox1.ItemIndex := I;` or `ComboBox1.Index := I;` should change the text of the combobox, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the line `ComboBox1.Index := -1;` which makes the combobox disappear. `Index` and `ItemIndex` have totally different purpose. Look at the documentation for [index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Index) and [ItemIndex](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomComboBox.ItemIndex).

This code work for me (I've put an Edit instead of `Marker.Descriptor.Title` for easy testing):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    I : Integer;
begin
    for I := 0 to ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 do begin
        if ComboBox1.Items[I].Equals(Edit1.Text) then begin
            ComboBox1.ItemIndex := I;
            break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'll test it the next days and let you know if it works for me